# Google Ads API - Get Ads daily clicks according to Age / Gender

Tags: python, google-ads-api, google-ads-script

Is it possible to get a daily Age / Gender breakdown for the specific Ad (`ad_group_ad`)?

Currently, I am trying to use the `age_range_view` and the `gender_view`, is there a way to  specify a specific Ad (`ad_group_ad.id`) in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, it's not possible. See more at GAQL documentation for Gender and Age Range views for v11 and v12:

- Gender View: [v11](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v11/gender_view_query_builder), [v12](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v12/gender_view_query_builder)
- Age Range View: [v11](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v11/age_range_view_query_builder), [v12](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v12/age_range_view_query_builder)

You can get data about ad group level but not about ads while working Gender and Age Range views.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Is there any other report that I can use to get the gender / age data on the keyword level?

Comment: The only way to get keyword-level age and gender data is to have single-keyword ad groups. When that's the case, the reports you get for an ad group naturally apply to a single keyword.